# How do I override the default bootstrap styles?

Tags: css, angular

I'm working on a webpage that's based on Angular and uses Bootstrap. When I add an Angular module, a .scss file is created. However, even with my .ts file specifying my .scss as styleUrl, the page still uses the bootstrap reboot styles.

Specifically I'm trying to simply change the page's background colour right now but it seems not to be possible. All it changes is the area also defined by this weird jumbotron box.

Do I maybe have to specify in my html code that I want to use the style sheet? I thought I already did this by linking the stylesheet in my .ts.

Here's my code for the component.ts and component.scss, as well as a screenshot from the inspector in chrome:

**.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
```

**.scss**

```
.jumbotron {
  background: none
}
body {
  background-color: #7EF911
}
```

[image: inspector]

How do I define my css as more important than bootstrap's default stuff?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you share your rendered DOM?

Comment: you should have some kind of global css/scss style file. Its usually in the `src` folder, and you can change it in `angular.json`, under the `styles` array (for dev and prod arrays)

Comment: @ra.design What is the rendered DOM? How do I find it?

Comment: @Dmitriy There is one, yeah but why does that override my scss for my components?
If I change that to the colour I want it doesn't do anything as well. It was also set to another colour before I even realised it was there and that apparently didn't affect anything...

Comment: @Konsti Lackner, well, it really depends, too little information given, check what order of styles included there,  is `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` before `style.css`, for example

Comment: @Dmitriy style.css isn't even there.
There's bootstrap.css, bootstrap-grid.css and bootstrap.reboot.css there

Comment: @Konsti Lackner, try adding one (after bootstrap) and creating according file. Then add your styles there, something like `"src/scss/main.scss"`, depends if you are using preprocessor. Well if your are configuring global styles, that`s the place where they belong

Comment: @DmitriyThat took me a minute. Ok, so I added the styles.scss that was already there to angular.json and placed it like this: ```"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override Bootstrap style try using `ng-deep`

```
:host ::ng-deep .jumbotron {
  background: none
}
:host ::ng-deep body {
  background-color: #7EF911
}
```